# How to subtract two temporary union tables column?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have Four Temp table :

I want count of this Two temp temp table

`(#OneyearExpiry + #OtherYearExpiry) as A`

`(#ONEYRCON+#OTHERYRCON) As B`

And then need to subtract A-B

can anybody help me into that ?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Use subqueries? We can't run the above, and we have no sample data or expected results here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using `except`

```
select * from
(
  select * from #OneyearExpiry
  union all
  select * from #OtherYearExpiry
) A

except

select * from
(
  select * from #ONEYRCON
  union all
  select * from #OTHERYRCON
) B
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , Its actually worked as per my request ..just once more question how can i add data for Two Grouping of union  
 and whole query data in three difference table.